# NodeJS Write binary file from https stream

Tags: node.js, https, stream, binary, chunks

Simple question I hope...

I want to use the following code from the Node documentation website for HTTPS (https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) but instead of stdout I want to write it to a file.

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

I found the following FS code for writing binary files but can't seem to successfully put the two together.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('myBinaryFile');
// creates random Buffer of 100 bytes
var buffer = crypto.randomBytes(100);
wstream.write(buffer);
// create another Buffer of 100 bytes and write
wstream.write(crypto.randomBytes(100));
wstream.end();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const wstream = fs.createWriteStream('myBinaryFile');

https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    wstream.write(d);
  });

  res.on('end', () => {
    wstream.end();
  })

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: Why not write in `res.on('data', ...)` ? That way you don't need to buffer the whole thing in memory.

Comment: Thanx, Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Looks so easy now you (both) have written it.